# Can I use DynamoDB Streams inside my Java Code to update/add data to my DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am using AWS Lambda(written in Java) to get data from DyanamoDB using DynamoDB Streams and then processing this data. Now I want to store the response of this processed data in the same DynamoDB Table and against the same primary key. Is it possible to use Streams to update the data back in the table or do I need to separately create a DyanamoDB Connection and then write my data into it ?? Kindly Suggest. Here is the code which I have used to read data from Stream and process it. I want to store the Response Status Code and actual Response in DB.

```
public String handleRequest(DynamodbEvent ddbEvent, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        Map<String,AttributeValue> newRecord = null;
        int index = 1;
        for (DynamodbStreamRecord record : ddbEvent.getRecords()) {
            logger.log("#######################################");
            logger.log("Processing Record - " + (index++));
            newRecord = record.getDynamodb().getNewImage();
            logger.log("Record Details - " + newRecord);

            String user = newRecord.get("user").getS();
            String password = newRecord.get("password").getS();
            String to = newRecord.get("to").getN();
            String from = newRecord.get("from").getN();
            String text = newRecord.get("text").getS();
            logger.log("Username - "+ user + " Password - " + password + " To - " + to + " From - " + from + " Text - " + text);

            String url = "http://www.sample.com";
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            String result = "";
            try {
                CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                logger.log("Response Status Code - " + response.getStatusLine().toString());
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    logger.log("Response - " + result);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.log(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    httpClient.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.log(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        return "Successfully processed " + ddbEvent.getRecords().size() + ".";
```

Comment: Try it and see. I doubt you can use the stream object to update the source DynamoDB table. Also, you're presumably going to have to deal with a form of recursive stream updates, where your update of the source table within your stream handler triggers another streamed updated which triggers the stream handler etc. ad infinitum. Probably not the best model. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569775/temporarily-disable-dynamodb-lambda-triggers-stream

Comment: @jarmod Thanks for your input. Yeah, I also thought so. Now planning to create a new table without any stream enabled and just store my data there.